# Integrating Spring Cloud Gateway and OAuth2 WITHOUT JWTs

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I am authenticating against an OAuth2 service that provides me 3 endpoints:

```
http://bobsoauth.com/oauth2/authorize
http://bobsoauth.com/oauth2/token
http://bobsoauth.com/oauth2/userdata
```

This service DOES NOT issue JWTs.

I need to use an Angular client application, connecting to a Spring Cloud Gateway, which in turn connects to multiple Spring Boot microservices.

Without JWTs, can I still use a token relay setup between the gateway and the microservices?

Answer (score 1):

Without JWTs, you'll have to configure your resource-servers with token introspection (`http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken()` instead of `http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()` in spring-security conf). This is far less efficient than JWT decoding because each micro-service has to submit token to authorization-server for each and every request it processes.

Sample here: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_introspection

The endpoint is usually called `introspect`, but I guess you'll have to figure out a way to use `userdata` in your case.

Have your Angular application authenticate against your authorization-server, and use the gateway just to forward `Authorization` header.

For Angular, I use [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client). Just put in the conf the URLs you mentioned in your question.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. I'll check into your solution and accept the answer if it works for me.

However, can the Angular client be considered secure? Or asked differently, is what I have enough to use PKCE from the Angular client?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, sorry if following does not answer. The lib I linked is listed in https://openid.net/developers/certified/ and supports authorization-code with PKCE. The login process won't happen in your Angular app: users will be redirected to `authorize` endpoint, login within a client (web form) provided by your authorization-server and then be redirected back to your Angular app.